# Extend a row with rowise() %>% do() when do() returns a vector

Tags: r, tidyverse, rowwise

How do I make this code more tidy?

```
as_tibble(t(mapply(pmf, x=lhs$mu, y=lhs$sigma)))
```

Here `pmf()` is a helper function.

```
pmf <- function(x, y) diff(pnorm(c(-Inf, -2, 0, 2, Inf), x, y))
```

This code takes the mean and standard deviation from each row,
and returns the probability mass function (PMF) for each bin.

So this

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
i     j       mu    sigma
<int> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>
  1     1     1 1.890402 2.879148
2     1     2 1.202357 2.655255
3     1     3 1.186224 2.127293
4     1     4 1.222278 2.228819
5     1     5 1.760214 2.324657
6     2     1 1.726712 2.574771
```

becomes this

```
# A tibble: 6 x 8
i     j       mu    sigma         V1        V2        V3        V4
<int> <int>    <dbl>    <dbl>      <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>     <dbl>
  1     1     1 1.890402 2.879148 0.08831027 0.1674140 0.2594582 0.4848175
2     1     2 1.202357 2.655255 0.11390009 0.2114385 0.2927260 0.3819354
3     1     3 1.186224 2.127293 0.06709483 0.2214568 0.3604183 0.3510301
4     1     4 1.222278 2.228819 0.07412598 0.2175836 0.3447228 0.3635676
5     1     5 1.760214 2.324657 0.05288144 0.1715857 0.3166106 0.4589223
6     2     1 1.726712 2.574771 0.07389306 0.1773358 0.2910357 0.4577354
```

after I use `bind_cols()` to add back the output.

I tried the following (using the same `pmf()` helper function).

```
pmf <- function(x, y) diff(pnorm(c(-Inf, -2, 0, 2, Inf), x, y))
lhs %>% rowwise() %>% do(k = pmf(.$mu, .$sigma))
```

But it returns the PMF as a list.
I would like the PMF as a row.
This doesn't work for me because downstream I need to apply a function across the rows on each column `V#`.

Is it possible to make this calculation more tidy?

FWIW, here is the full calculation.

```
library(tidyverse)

# find PMF from mu and sigma
pmf <- function(x, y) diff(pnorm(c(-Inf, -2, 0, 2, Inf), x, y))

# find mean*variance for each column (i.e., PMF bin) __across rows___
mean_var <- function(x) mean(x)*var(x)

# here are my data
lhs <- tibble(i = rep(1:2, each=5),
              j = rep(1:5, times=2),
              mu = 1 + runif(2*5),
              sigma = 2 + runif(2*5))

# find PMF from mu and sigma
rhs <- as_tibble(t(mapply(pmf, x=lhs$mu, y=lhs$sigma)))

# downstream calculations
ans <- 
  lhs %>% 
  bind_cols(rhs) %>% 
  group_by(i) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(starts_with('V')), funs(mean_var)) %>% 
  gather(bin, mean_var, -i) %>% 
  group_by(i) %>% 
  summarise(ambg = sum(mean_var))

# this finds PMF from mu and sigma, but as a list; I need a row
lhs %>% rowwise() %>% do(k = pmf(.$mu, .$sigma))
```

Comment: So is the problem that you don't want to use `cbind()`? I suppose you could use `join()` or `group_by` & `summarize` from `dplyr`. Just unsure about the question here.

Comment: @zfisher I would like to return a row from `rowise() %>% do()` when `do()` returns a vector. I would like to replace the `as_tibble(t(mapply(...)))` line with something more readable and maintainable.

Comment: @RichardHerron there are other ways to do it, but I wouldn't say they are better necessarily. For instance, you can modify your function to return a single-row tibble. You can also use other commands like `Reduce("rbind", map2(df$mu, df$sigma, ~pmf(.x,.y)))` in `tidyverse` verbs. The issue is that converting a vector to a single-row data frame (or tibble) is not easily done with a single command.

Comment: @RichardHerron just to clarify, a row is not a data structure within R. The reason why `do()` returns a vector is because you've defined it that way in your `pmf` function.

Comment: @ChiPak Thanks. So this an edge case without a simple (tidy only) solution. I use R just enough to end up with either wacky solutions or wasting time to find out that my solution is already at minimum wackiness. Thanks.

Comment: @zfisher Good point. `row` isn't a data structure. But I want to "extend" the row that I have. Maybe a row is a like a lap? A row only exists in a tibble or data frame. Chi points out that this may be as good as it gets. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RichardHerron you could post another question asking for people's best methods for converting a vector to a single-row tibble. You're likely to get tons of different answers you can compare among.